# printf() within a C-function outputs wrong result in Python when using ctypes

Tags: python, c, printf, ctypes

I have the following problem. Any help would be appreciated :)

I am trying to call a C function from Python using ctypes. I have been successful in sharing the shared library (.dll on Windows with MS Visual Studio 2017) to Python 3.6.3.

There is a problem when I try to call the following function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void printFunc()
{
    printf("hello world !!");
    //fflush(stdout);
}
```

I would like to see the output at Python interpreter as 'hello world !!' when I execute

```
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('path\\to\\sharedLibrary.dll')
mydll.printFunc.restype = None
mydll.printFunc()
```

Currently I see no output (because, the restype is None) when I execute the above code.

Expected output at Python interpreter after running the script:

```
>>> hello world !!
```

Any ideas please ??

Comment: You are probably using an IDE and stdout is redirected or replaced.  Run it in a Windows console and you should see the output.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen, But I would like to see the output at python interpreter. Is that possible, and if yes, what changes should I make ?

Comment: Depends on what you are using. May not be possible with your IDE.  Did you try running Python in a console?

Comment: How do you run Python? Also please show the entire Python script (what is cdll?)

Comment: @MarkTolonen, Yes I tried running Python script in a console and it worked. Thanks for your help !! But I am still interested to know if there is, anything exists, a possiblity to see the same output in python interpreter.

Comment: @n.m. I was running Python from the script itself. Simply pressing F5 will serve your purpose. But in my case, as I cannot the output of printf() within a C function, currently I am using console to view the output.                       cdll is used to export the dynamic library when wrapping. It's part of 'ctypes' module.

Comment: You were running Python from the Visual Studio IDE. I'm not sure where exactly you was looking for your script output, but it should have went to a console window that IDE should have opened, as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/rSz6Oin.png)

Comment: @n.m. this is exactly what I was looking for but when I have run the script, IDE has not opened any console window to display the output. So, I have opened the cmd and run the script from there as, for ex, 'file_name.py' and then I saw the output.                                               Your solution seems interesting to me. Can you please let me know (the steps) how have you done this ?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. Create a python project and run it. Note the console window may open behind the IDE window.

Comment: @n.m. But the console window is not opening with my example. Is there any change for example, PATH or something (I don't know exactly) to make the console window popup automatically. Any idea ?

Comment: I have no idea, I made zero changes to my VS installation. Try creating a new project with defaullt settings.

Answer (score 1):

- Your "hello world !!" should be printed in any case. Maybe stdout is redirected to somewhere, where you can't see it? Or line buffering is an issue, try `fflush(stdout)` after your `printf()` call.
- The default return type for those functions is `int`. You do not explicitely return an int, so just some value which happened to be in some cpu register is taken as return value. Chances are, that it is the return value of the `printf()`, which is 14 in this case (the number of characters printed)
- You can change the return type to `void` by issuing: `mydll.printFunc.restype = None`, then you shouldn't observe any integer as return value of the (python) function call.
- If you want to have the output at your python interpreter instead of stdout, you will have to *return* the string from your function instead of passing it to `printf()` and adjust the return type accordingly:

.

```
 __declspec(dllexport) char *printFunc() {
     return "hello world !!";
 }
```

And in your python interpreter:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('path\\to\\sharedLibrary.dll')
>>> mydll.printFunc.restype = c_char_p
>>> mydll.printFunc()
'hello world !!'
```

Comment: Hello @Ctx, I have inserted 'fflush(stdout)' after printf() in C program and also, changed the mydll.printFunc.restype to None. Unfortunately, I still see the output as an integer i.e.  26.                                                                                Any other suggestions please ?

Comment: @Vandith hm, can you c&p the actual session with inputs and outputs and edit it in your question above?

Comment: I am sorry; there was no output after the changes. The output 26 that I have mentioned was from other function.

Comment: @n.m. I have reduced the code to exactly what I have and the expected behaviour. Le t me know if this you have solution for this. Thanks!

Comment: @Vandith I have updated the answer, maybe this is what you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately your solution will not help my case. I have an existing C library already and I would want export it to Python. This is the small code snippet that  I have shown you.                                                                                                Anyways, as suggested by Mark Tolonen, one can view the output in console. I tried and it worked.

Comment: fflush(stdout) --> This fixed my issue, thanks so much.